# DELL Monitor with in-built camera for Linux OS - Any driver related issues?

Tags: linux, drivers, display, camera

I am planning on buying a DELL Monitor for my desktop. Now, I would like to have one which has an in-built camera. Also, my operating system is going to be Linux. Will I have any driver related issues for monitor as well as for the in-built camera.

Any suggestions on the monitor models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably no. I didn't ever heard about *monitor* driver issues in any OS: the driver's job is to talk to video adapter. And all new USB cameras are [UVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UVC)-compliant: UVC is unified USB camera standard that is fully supported by recent Linux versions.